# My own NM binary

Tags: c, linux

Hello everybody it's my first post on this great site, sorry for mistake.

I’m student. I must do my own nm binary. I started by 64 bits and I have a strange problem.

The number of nsyms is different between my nm and the real nm. I don’t know why…

`(*nm)->fd` = the fd from the binary file

`(*nm)->buff` = struct returned by `fstat`

`(*nm)->data` = the pointer from the return of `mmap`

This is the code to 64 bits :

```
    #include "../incs/ft_nm.h"

static bool                 print_output(t_nm **nm, struct symtab_command *sym)
{
    if (nm == NULL || *nm == NULL || sym == NULL)
        ERROR_EXIT("Invalid arguments 2", __FILE__, NULL, NULL);
    printf("nb symbole : %d\n", sym->nsyms);
    return (true);
}

static bool                 loop_func_64(t_nm **nm, struct mach_header_64 *header, struct load_command *lc)
{
    uint32_t                i;

    if (nm == NULL || *nm == NULL || header == NULL || lc == NULL)
        ERROR_EXIT("Invalid arguments", __FILE__, NULL, NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (i++ < header->ncmds)
    {
        if (lc->cmd == LC_SYMTAB)
            return (print_output(nm, (void *)lc));
        if ((void*)(lc = (void *)lc + lc->cmdsize) > (void*)(*nm)->end)
            ERROR_EXIT("Ptr lc over the end 2", __FILE__, del_nm, nm);
    }
    return (false);
}

bool                        func_64(t_nm **nm)
{
    struct mach_header_64   *header;
    struct load_command     *lc;

    if (nm == NULL || *nm == NULL)
        ERROR_EXIT("NM = NULL", __FILE__, NULL, NULL);
    header = (struct mach_header_64*)(*nm)->data;
    if((void*)(lc = (void*)(*nm)->data + sizeof(*header)) > (void*)(*nm)->end)
        ERROR_EXIT("Ptr lc over the end", __FILE__, del_nm, nm);
    return (loop_func_64(nm, header, lc));
}
```

Can you help me to find where the difference from please?

Thx all

Comment: The code formatting is terrible. Start by fixing it.

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger

Comment: I did pointers for me are ok

Comment: @FlorianPasquereau - is that an answer to my debugger question? I didnt mention pointers at all. I just asked if you stepped through your code with a debugger, watching where it goes wrong and doesnt do what you expect

Comment: When i check with gdb values from header and lc they looks good. I think the problem is at the cast between the struct symtab_command and struct load_command in the function loop_func_64 at the second line in the while

Comment: so where does it go wrong then, follow through your code

Comment: this is the value of `sym = {cmd = 2
, cmdsize = 24
, symoff = 17136
, nsyms = 186
, stroff = 20212
, strsize = 1984
}` I should have 52 nsyms like nm

Comment: How may symbols does `nm -a` report?

Comment: I have 186 answers with nm -a. I found where the problem from. When I used -g when i compiled... Without -g i have the right number of symbol. n_stab to show what i need thx everybody